# Pandas fromat column multiple sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

With the following code, I manage to create excel files for each of the Country's but I am not able to format excel columns:

```
df=TOT.reset_index()
for n, g in df.groupby('Country'):
    X = n.strip(" ")
    out_path = "C:/temp/" + n.strip(" ") + ".xlsx" 
    C =TOTSPPerc.reset_index(level=0)[TOTSP.reset_index(level=0).Country==n].drop('Country', axis=1)  
    B =TOTPerc.reset_index(level=0)[TOTPerc.reset_index(level=0).Country==n].drop('Country', axis=1) 
    A= TOTcntPerc.drop('Country', axis=1) 
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path , engine='xlsxwriter')

    format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})

    A.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Country")
    B.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Stores")
    C.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="SPs")

    writer.save()
    print(n)
```

I need to format column `B:F` for each of the 3 sheets for each of the created files.

Comment: Check [XlsxWriter examples](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) - look for `set_column()` on that page...

Comment: Added this but does not work:    
    worksheet.set_column('A:H', format2)

Answer (score 4):

You can [set custom format](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html) to each sheet:

```
for n, g in df.groupby('Country'):
    print (g)
    #your code

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path , engine='xlsxwriter')

    A.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Country")
    B.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Stores")
    C.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="SPs")

    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet1 = writer.sheets['Country']
    worksheet2 = writer.sheets['Stores']
    worksheet3 = writer.sheets['SPs']

    format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})
    worksheet1.set_column('B:F', 18, format2)
    worksheet2.set_column('B:F', 18, format2)
    worksheet3.set_column('B:F', 18, format2)

    writer.save()
```

And more dynamic solution:

```
for n, g in df.groupby('Country'):
    print (g)

    #your code

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path , engine='xlsxwriter')

    dfs = [A,B,C]
    sheetnames = ['Country','Stores','SPs']
    for i, df1 in enumerate(dfs):
        df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetnames[i])
        workbook  = writer.book
        worksheet1 = writer.sheets[sheetnames[i]]
        format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})
        worksheet1.set_column('B:F', 18, format2)

    writer.save()
```